# How does the compiler determine when is it safe to RVO?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, return-value-optimization

How does the compiler determine when it is safe to RVO? And no, I don't mean the rvalue, but the lvalue - if I understand correctly RVO works by "forwarding" the target address to the method, so it returns into the target address instead of the address of a temporary and then copy/assign to the target.

But how does the compiler know it is safe to perform a RVO? What if the lvalue already has some data in it, including dynamically allocated resource? A RVO in such a case may result in a leaked resource. Mayhaps there are some rules which specify whether it is applicable to perform the optimization or stick to using copy or assignment?

Comment: RVO cannot result in a leaked resource (for a sane type). The object is constructed in the same place the called expects the return value to be. The exact rules may depend on the implementation though, they are not mandated by the standard.

Comment: How can it result in a leaked resource? It behaves like if you passed the variable you're copying to as a reference parameter

Comment: If it is a "constructor" type of function which allocates dynamic resource to a member pointer, running that function twice on the address of the same object will allocate the resource twice, I assume a "constructor type" function will directly allocate instead of checking if the pointer already allocates. Which would make sense for a "constructor type" function. So the first resource will leak...

Comment: Why would the constructor be called twice?

Comment: @sftrabbit - well, I explicitly put it in "" and called it a "constructor" type of function, not a constructor per se. Let's say ` T a = foo1(); .... a = foo2()` - it is safe for `foo1` to apply RVO, but if `foo2` applies it, dynamic resources will leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RVO can only initialise a new object, not reassign an existing object. So in this case:

```
Thing thing = make_thing();
```

the address of `thing` is passed to the function, which initialises it in place.

In this case:

```
thing = make_thing();
```

RVO (in general) creates a temporary, which is then assigned to `thing`. There will be no leaks or similar issues, as long as the type is correctly assignable. Since it's a temporary *rvalue*, it can be moved from, which might be more efficient than copying. If the type is trivially assignable, then this assignment could also be elided - the compiler will know whether this is the case when it chooses how to call the function.

Comment: So, there is a rule "rvo can only be applied to "new" objects" but how does the compiler determine when an object is new? If it is only instantiated and nothing else? Does that mean that even operations that do not technically obstruct rvo will disable the optimization if used with the object between the instantiation and point of rvo?

Comment: @user2341104: The rules for when copies and moves can be elided are quite complicated, but that's a reasonable simplification. The compiler can see that the object is new because the function call is part of its initialiser. If it's being reassigned (as in my second example), then (in general) RVO is used to initialise a temporary to assign from, as I described.

Comment: So, `T t = foo()` will use RVO, but `T t; t = foo()` will not (with nothing else happening in between the two statements)? In other words, does the compiler need the assignment to be part of the instantiation or maybe it has other ways of determine if assignment is the first method being called after the point of instantiation?

Comment: @user2341104: The first case isn't assignment - it's initialisation. RVO can be used for initialisation, but not (in general) for assignment.

Comment: @user2341104 It will (probably) use RVO, but it won't elide the copy/move assignment from the return value to `t`. The reason that assignment is not elided is because some work is needed to ensure the object moves from one state to another without leaking. A copy/move can only be elided when it's during construction, because nothing has yet been allocated.

Comment: Note that the assignment case will still benefit from move constructors, as the unnamed temporary can be moved from. @user2341104:

Comment: @MikeSeymour - but is there such a difference, you say it is not assignment but initialization, but it still uses the assignment operator, does the compiler distinguish between the two contexts of the assignment operator? Isn't the assignment sill an "initialization" if it is used on a non-initialized object, but not on the line of its instantiation?

Comment: @user2341104 It's not the assignment operator. In a declaration, like `T t = ...;` the `=` is part of the initialisation, and not the assignment operator. The assignment operator can only appear inside an expression, and `T t = ...;` is not an expression.

Comment: @sftrabbit - but it uses the assignment operator (in the case of no rvo)?

Also, I wonder how does the compiler even know what the `=` operator is doing, for primitive types - sure, but rvo doesn't really make sense there, but for user types, the `=` operator can do anything the developer wishes.

Comment: @user2341104 It will never use the assignment operator - it uses the copy/move constructor. Don't let the `=` fool you. In this case, `T t = foo();` is equivalent to `T t(foo());`. You can't call the assignment operator on an object that isn't constructed yet. On your second point, you're really asking about the copy/move constructors - and the compiler doesn't care what they do. The compiler can elide them regardless. It is expected that a responsible C++ programmer will not implement copy/move constructors with side effects.

Comment: @sftrabbit - let me make sure I got this right. `T t1(t2)` uses the copy constructor, and so does `T t1 = t2` and NOT the assignment operator?

Comment: @user2341104 Correct.

Comment: Hmm, this seems counter-intuitive, I expected that typing the assignment operator would result in an assignment regardless of the context.

Comment: @user2341104: Indeed, C++ syntax is often counter-intuitive and context-dependent, as a result of evolving from older languages over several decades. `=` is only an assignment operator in an assignment expression. The same token is also used in a declaration to indicate initialisation (and in other contexts like function declarations and using directives with different meanings again).

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here as to what RVO is.  RVO is independent of what the caller is doing; it occurs in the function doing the return.  (Other optimizations, like the ones described in the section on initialization, do apply.)

Comment: @user2341104 It's _not_ the assignment operator.  There are several symbols in C++ which can be both operators and punctuation: `=`, `,`, `<`, `>`, '(' and `)` at least.  In the case of a declaration `=` is not an operator, but punctuation (except in cases like `T t = a = b;`, where the first `=` is punctuation, but the second an operator).

Comment: @MikeSeymour `=` has signified both assignment and initialization since the earliest days of C.  Without user defined constructors, of course, the distinction is really not very significant; the compiler generates exactly the same code for `int i = 42;` and `int i; i = 42;`, even though the `=` signifies initialization in the first case, and assignment in the second.  But the two cases have been distinct, grammatically, since the very beginnings of C.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, I'm sure that aspect of C has always been the same, and I'm fairly sure I didn't say otherwise. I just said that it's (also) the case in modern C++ (due to its evolution from C), which is rather more relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Return value optimization is a particular case of copy elision. It may occur in the following situation as described by the standard:

> in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv- unqualified type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the function’s return value

There is no reason this should result in a memory leak. If the class performs some dynamic allocation in its constructor, this will happen when the object is constructed directly into the function's return value.

---

In response to your comment (where `foo1` and `foo2` both construct `T` objects and return them):

```
T a = foo1();
a = foo2();
```

We're not only looking at RVO here, but another kind of copy elision that occurs when attempting to construct an object from a temporary.

In the first line, two copies/moves can be elided:

1. Returning the constructed object from `foo1`
2. Copying the returned object into `a`

That is, the object constructed in `foo1` can be directly created in the location of `a`. If the constructor dynamically allocates some object, that will only be done once, for the `a` object.

In the second line, a single copy/move can be elided - only the return from the function. So the object that `foo2` constructs will be created directly in the return value of the function, then it will be *copy/move assigned* into `a`. Copy/move assignments aren't elided.

It is then up to the copy/move assignment operator to ensure that the original allocated resource is discarded safely and the only remaining resource is the one that was created inside `foo2`.

Comment: @user2341104 But it is only constructed once, directly into the function's return value.

Comment: see my comment to the question

Comment: @user2341104 Response in my answer.